# chef cookbook for database creation getting error while knife ssh 'sudo chef-client'

Tags: database, ssh, chef-infra, chef-recipe, cookbook

I am very new to chef ! I am following learn.chef.io document  https://learn.chef.io/manage-a-web-app/ubuntu/apply-and-verify-your-database-configuration/  to create cookbooks for database creation ! Getting following error ! So please help me out to figure out what is wrong here !

```
$ knife ssh 54.153.93.47 'sudo chef-client' --manual-list --ssh-user ubuntu --identity-file /home/ashish/Keys/chef1.pem

54.153.93.47 Starting Chef Client, version 12.4.2

54.153.93.47 resolving cookbooks for run list: ["awesome_customers"]

54.153.93.47 Synchronizing Cookbooks:

54.153.93.47 - yum-mysql-community

54.153.93.47 - firewall

54.153.93.47 - awesome_customers

54.153.93.47 - apt

54.153.93.47 - chef-sugar

54.153.93.47 - httpd

54.153.93.47 - poise

54.153.93.47 - build-essential

54.153.93.47 - mariadb

54.153.93.47 - database

54.153.93.47 - mysql

54.153.93.47 - mysql2_chef_gem

54.153.93.47 - openssl

54.153.93.47 - smf

54.153.93.47 - postgresql

54.153.93.47 - yum

54.153.93.47 - rbac

54.153.93.47 - yum-epel

54.153.93.47 Compiling Cookbooks...

54.153.93.47 [2015-09-28T13:18:36+00:00] WARN: You declared a new resource Chef::Provider::HttpdServiceRhelSysvinit for resource httpd_service, but it comes alphabetically after Chef::Provider::HttpdServiceRhelSystemd and has the same filters ({:platform_family=>["rhel", "fedora", "suse"]}), so it will not be used. Use override: true if you want to use it for httpd_service.

54.153.93.47 [2015-09-28T13:18:36+00:00] WARN: You are overriding httpd_service on {:platform_family=>["rhel", "fedora", "suse"]} with Chef::Provider::HttpdServiceRhelSystemd: used to be Chef::Provider::HttpdServiceRhelSysvinit. Use override: true if this is what you intended.

54.153.93.47 [2015-09-28T13:18:36+00:00] WARN: You declared a new resource Chef::Provider::HttpdServiceRhelSysvinit for resource httpd_service, but it comes alphabetically after Chef::Provider::HttpdServiceRhelSystemd and has the same filters ({:platform_family=>["rhel", "fedora", "suse"]}), so it will not be used. Use override: true if you want to use it for httpd_service.

54.153.93.47 [2015-09-28T13:18:36+00:00] WARN: You declared a new resource Chef::Provider::HttpdServiceRhelSysvinit for resource httpd_service, but it comes alphabetically after Chef::Provider::HttpdServiceRhelSystemd and has the same filters ({:platform_family=>["rhel", "fedora", "suse"]}), so it will not be used. Use override: true if you want to use it for httpd_service.

54.153.93.47

54.153.93.47 ================================================================================

54.153.93.47 Recipe Compile Error in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/awesome_customers/recipes/default.rb

54.153.93.47 ================================================================================

54.153.93.47

54.153.93.47 NameError

54.153.93.47 ---------

54.153.93.47 No resource, method, or local variable named `chef' for `Chef::Recipe "database"'

54.153.93.47

54.153.93.47 Cookbook Trace:

54.153.93.47 ---------------

54.153.93.47 /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/awesome_customers/recipes/database.rb:15:in `from_file'

54.153.93.47 /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/awesome_customers/recipes/default.rb:11:in `from_file'

54.153.93.47

54.153.93.47 Relevant File Content:

54.153.93.47 ----------------------

54.153.93.47 /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/awesome_customers/recipes/database.rb:

54.153.93.47

54.153.93.47 8: action :install

54.153.93.47 9: end

54.153.93.47 10:

54.153.93.47 11: mysql_client 'default' do

54.153.93.47 12: action :create

54.153.93.47 13: end

54.153.93.47 14:

54.153.93.47 15>> password_secret = chef::EncryptedDataBagItem.load_secret(node['awesome_customers']['passwords']['secret_path'])

54.153.93.47 16: root_password_data_bag_item = Chef::EncryptedDataBagItem.load('passwords', 'sql_server_root_password', password_secret)

54.153.93.47 17:

54.153.93.47 18: mysql_service 'default' do

54.153.93.47 19: initial_root_password root_password_data_bag_item['password']

54.153.93.47 20: action [:create, :start]

54.153.93.47 21: end

54.153.93.47 22:

54.153.93.47 23: # Create the database instance.

54.153.93.47 24: #mysql_database 'products' do

54.153.93.47

54.153.93.47

54.153.93.47 Running handlers:

54.153.93.47 [2015-09-28T13:18:36+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers

54.153.93.47 Running handlers complete

54.153.93.47 [2015-09-28T13:18:36+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete

54.153.93.47 Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 2.549055767 seconds

54.153.93.47 [2015-09-28T13:18:37+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out

54.153.93.47 [2015-09-28T13:18:37+00:00] ERROR: No resource, method, or local variable named `chef' for `Chef::Recipe "database"'

54.153.93.47 [2015-09-28T13:18:37+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

as i am new to this i am not able to find error ! plz help me out to find what is wrong !

ps : I have ec2 instance as chef node & open source hosted chef server. 
I have stopped & restarted the instance since last successful creation of previous cookbooks for web server creation !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read your logs, chef is kind enough to mark the problematic line (emphasis is mine):

> 54.153.93.47 NameError
>
> 54.153.93.47 ---------
>
> 54.153.93.47 No resource, method, or local variable named `**c**hef' for `Chef::Recipe "database"'
>
> *[ .... ] Stripped a part to shorten*
>
> 54.153.93.47 14:
>
> 54.153.93.47 15**>>** password_secret = **c**hef::EncryptedDataBagItem.load_secret(node['awesome_customers']['passwords']['secret_path'])
>
> 54.153.93.47 16: root_password_data_bag_item = **C**hef::EncryptedDataBagItem.load('passwords', 'sql_server_root_password', password_secret)
>
> 54.153.93.47 17:

You just have a typo of a lowercase `c` for `Chef::` in your `password_secret` line

Comment: I tried with both upper "Chef" & lower case "chef" but got same error ! bty after modification i ran : $ berks install
Resolving cookbook dependencies...
Fetching 'awesome_customers' from source at .
Using apt (2.6.1)Using awesome_customers (0.2.0) from source at .
Using poise (2.3.2)
Using postgresql (3.4.16)
Using rbac (1.0.3)
Using smf (2.2.7)
Using yum (3.7.1)
Using yum-epel (0.6.3)
Using yum-mysql-community (0.1.18)

Comment: $ berks upload awesome_customers
Skipping awesome_customers (0.2.0) (frozen)

$ knife ssh 54.153.93.47 'sudo chef-client' --manual-list --ssh-user ubuntu --identity-file /home/ashish/Keys/chef1.pem

Comment: Indeed once modified you have to upload the new version on the chef-server.... This mean you have to bump the version in metadata.rb or force the upload